# How to change text color using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem in changing color if the text in javascript.
html:

```
   `<div>
       <strong id="text"><strong>
    </div>`
```

here is my javascript:

```
  ` function calculate(){
     var a = 1;
     var b = 2;
     var c = 3;
     var d = 4;
     var sumA = a+b;
     var sumB = c+d;
       if(sumA>sumB){
          $('#text').text().fontcolor("blue"); //change color to blue
       }else{
          $('#text').text().fontcolor("red"); //change color to red
       }
    }`
```

None of the text changed the color

Comment: plese show your corresponding html

Comment: What is `fontcolor()`? It's not part of standard jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
$('#text').css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the css property to change any css for an element:

```
$('#text').css('color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

//JAVASCRIPT

```
  document.getElementById("text").style.color = "red";
```

//jQuery

```
$('#text').css("color","red");
```

Answer (score 0):

The .text() function returns a string, not the element that you are trying to recolour so this does not do anything as a string can not be "coloured".

See the following example:

```js
$('#test').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='test'>Hello World</span>
```